# Why is the denominator and numerator of Fourier coefficient (in Fourier series(exponential) expansion) have a conjugate of the exponential set?

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

In the exponential Fourier series, the coefficient Fn takes both the conjugate and original of the exponential set in its denominator and numerator.
This doesn't make any sense when seen from the principle of error of least squares which is supposed to derive the Fourier coefficient. 
Where am I going wrong?Please explain.

Comment: You're going to need to give some more context for the problem. What do you mean by "the approximation signal"?

Comment: @eyeballfrog sorry, just lost in the flow of reading. The approximate signal is just the orthogonal exponential set. Just the e power i *w knot *t*n. Edited the question, thanks for pointing it out.